# Mouse wheel issues in VS Code on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, mouse

The mouse is buggy in VS Code on Ubuntu. Periodically, the wheel will scroll the open document much more than necessary. And sometimes scrolling is carried out in the wrong direction (turned the wheel up, and the page scrolled down and vice versa). I tried to change the mouse - the problem remained.